# How simplify a select query that contains many inner-selects and increase performance in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

Given below is my `select query`

```
  SELECT 
   gtab04.Productid,
   gtab04.Product,
   gtab04.SaleUnit ,
   gtab04.Packing,
   gtab04.ConvFact,
   gtab04.PTR,
   gtab04.MRP, 
   gtab04.PRate,
   gtab04.PTR1,
   gtab04.PTR2,
   gtab04.Location,
   0 As ManufId,
   gtab07.PatentId,
   gtab07.Patent,
   gtab07.PatentCd,
   gtab15.TaxId,
   gtab15.TaxName, 
   gtab15.TaxType,
   gtab15.TaxRate, 
   gtab15.TxOMRP,
   ''::text As Manufacture,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
      SELECT gtab10.Productid FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab09.TranId = 
      gtab10.TranId WHERE  gtab10.Productid = gtab04.Productid AND      
      gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId AND gtab09.acyrid = 7 limit 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   
      AS 
   StkEntered,
      (SELECT SUM(gtab10.qty) FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab10.TranId =  
      gtab09.TranId WHERE gtab10.Productid = gtab04.Productid AND    
      gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId AND gtab09.vrid = 6 AND gtab09.acyrid = 7) 
      +
      (SELECT SUM(gtab10.qty) FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab10.TranId =  
      gtab09.TranId  WHERE gtab10.Productid = gtab04.Productid AND   
      gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId AND gtab09.vrid in (10,11,23,42,35) AND      
      gtab09.trdate < Cast('2014-06-01' AS timestamp) AND gtab09.acyrid = 7) 
   AS 
   OpeningInQty
      (SELECT SUM(gtab10.qty)FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab10.TranId =    
      gtab09.TranId  WHERE gtab04.Productid = gtab10.Productid AND     
      gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId AND gtab09.vrid in( 12,32,33,44 ,45 ,46, 47 ,48 ,     
      49,18 , 34 ,25,27 ,15,26,24 , 43 ,36) AND gtab09.trdate < Cast('2014-06-01'   AS    
      timestamp) AND gtab09.acyrid = 7) AS 
   OpeningOutQty,
   0 AS PurchQty, 
   0 AS SRetQty, 
   0 AS PerInQty, 
   0 AS SaleQty, 
   0 AS StockInQty,
   0 AS StockOutQty, 
   0 AS SaleAmt, 
   0 AS DamageQty, 
   0 AS PRetQty, 
   0 AS PerOutQty,
      (SELECT SUM(gtab10.qty) FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab10.TranId =     
      gtab09.TranId WHERE gtab04.Productid = gtab10.Productid AND     
      gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId AND gtab09.vrid in (12 ,32 ,33 ,44 ,45 ,46 ,47,48    
      ,49) AND (gtab09.trdate BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31')
      ) AS 
   PrMthSaleQty, 
      (SELECT (SUM(gtab10.qty * gtab10.ptr) ) FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON   
      gtab10.TranId = gtab09.TranId WHERE gtab04.Productid = gtab10.Productid   AND    
      gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId AND gtab09.vrid in( 12, 32 , 33 , 44 ,45 ,46 , 47    
      ,48 , 49) AND (FreeOrRpl = 0 OR FreeOrRpl = 2) AND (gtab09.trdate BETWEEN  '2014-   
      05-01' AND '2014-05-31')
      ) AS 
   PrMthSaleAmt, 
   gtab04.LandCost,
   gtab05.PTR AS BatchPTR,
      (case when (
      gtab05.Fqty -  gtab05.FIQty)>0 then (gtab05.Fqty -  gtab05.FIQty) else 0 end) as 
   IssdFreeQty, 
   gtab05.MRP AS BatchMRP, 
   gtab05.PRate AS BatchPRate, 
   gtab04.StdPack,  
      (date_part('day',  (Select Min(Expiry) From gtab05 WHERE  gtab05.Productid =    
      gtab04.Productid And gtab05.Qty > gtab05.IQty)-Cast('2014-06-20' AS    
      timestamp))) AS 
   ExpDys, 
      (SELECT  gtab09.TrDate FROM gtab09 INNER JOIN gtab10 ON gtab09.TranId  
      =gtab10.TranId   
      where gtab09.VrId in (12,32,33,44,45,46, 47,48,49) And   
      gtab10.ProductId =gtab04.ProductId order by TrDate desc limit 1) As 
   LastSaleDate ,
   GTAB05.BatchId, 
   0 AS FreeSaleQty, 
   0 AS ReplSaleQty 
FROM
   gtab04 INNER JOIN  gtab15 ON gtab04.TaxId = gtab15.TaxId  LEFT JOIN gtab05 ON  
   gtab04.Productid = gtab05.Productid   INNER JOIN gtab07 ON gtab07.Patentid =      
   gtab04.Patentid  WHERE (gtab04.Masked = False AND gtab04.Banned = false)  AND  
   gtab04.patentid in  (321, 313 , 267 , 431) ORDER BY Patent, gtab04.Product
```

[EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://explain.depesz.com/s/lDn)

as you can see in the above *select* i have used many *inner selects*, while adding these these  *inner selects* to the main *select* the overall performance will slow down taking many time to execute.
i think (*no am sure*) that my *select query plan* is *poor*.

Please help to improve this `Query`.

**EDIT**

---

[Sample data(.backup) and query plan](http://www.mediafire.com/download/mw97vrdgruf8558/data_backup_PostgreSQL9.2_.rar)

Answer (score 2):

*Optimizations*:

1. Get all aggregates calc in single select - group by query.
2. Replace subselects with left join
3. Additional restriction in inner query based on outer conditions.

Get this as such:

```
with gtab4_5 as (
    select 
        gtab04.Productid, gtab05.BatchId
    FROM
       gtab04 
    LEFT JOIN gtab05 
        ON gtab04.Productid = gtab05.Productid  
    WHERE (gtab04.Masked = False AND gtab04.Banned = false)  
        AND  gtab04.patentid in  (321, 313 , 267 , 431) 
)
  SELECT 
   gtab04.Productid,
   gtab04.Product,
   gtab04.SaleUnit ,
   gtab04.Packing,
   gtab04.ConvFact,
   gtab04.PTR,
   gtab04.MRP, 
   gtab04.PRate,
   gtab04.PTR1,
   gtab04.PTR2,
   gtab04.Location,
   0 As ManufId,
   gtab07.PatentId,
   gtab07.Patent,
   gtab07.PatentCd,
   gtab15.TaxId,
   gtab15.TaxName, 
   gtab15.TaxType,
   gtab15.TaxRate, 
   gtab15.TxOMRP,
   ''::text As Manufacture,
   stats_ags.StkEntered AS StkEntered,
   stats_ags.OpeningInQty as OpeningInQty,
   stats_ags.OpeningOutQty as OpeningOutQty,
   0 AS PurchQty, 
   0 AS SRetQty, 
   0 AS PerInQty, 
   0 AS SaleQty, 
   0 AS StockInQty,
   0 AS StockOutQty, 
   0 AS SaleAmt, 
   0 AS DamageQty, 
   0 AS PRetQty, 
   0 AS PerOutQty,
   stats_ags.PrMthSaleQty as PrMthSaleQty,
   stats_ags.PrMthSaleAmt as PrMthSaleAmt,
   gtab04.LandCost,
   gtab05.PTR AS BatchPTR,
      (case when (
      gtab05.Fqty -  gtab05.FIQty)>0 then (gtab05.Fqty -  gtab05.FIQty) else 0 end) as 
   IssdFreeQty, 
   gtab05.MRP AS BatchMRP, 
   gtab05.PRate AS BatchPRate, 
   gtab04.StdPack,  
      (date_part('day',  (Select Min(Expiry) From gtab05 WHERE  gtab05.Productid =    
      gtab04.Productid And gtab05.Qty > gtab05.IQty)-Cast('2014-06-20' AS    
      timestamp))) AS 
   ExpDys, 
   stats_ags.LastSaleDate as LastSaleDate ,
   GTAB05.BatchId, 
   0 AS FreeSaleQty, 
   0 AS ReplSaleQty 
FROM
   gtab04 
INNER JOIN  gtab15 
    ON gtab04.TaxId = gtab15.TaxId  
LEFT JOIN gtab05 
    ON gtab04.Productid = gtab05.Productid   
INNER JOIN gtab07 
    ON gtab07.Patentid = gtab04.Patentid  
left join (
        SELECT gtab10_9.Productid, gtab10_9.BatchId, 
            max( case 
                when gtab10_9.acyrid = 7 
                then gtab10_9.Productid else null 
            end) as StkEntered,
            SUM( case 
                when gtab10_9.acyrid = 7 and ( 
                    gtab10_9.vrid = 6 
                or (
                    gtab10_9.vrid in (10,11,23,42,35) 
                    AND gtab10_9.trdate < Cast('2014-06-01' AS timestamp) 
                ) ) 
                then gtab10_9.qty else 0 
            end) as OpeningInQty,
            SUM( case 
                when gtab10_9.acyrid = 7 
                    and gtab10_9.vrid in( 12,32,33,44 ,45 ,46, 47 ,48 , 49,18 , 34 ,25,27 ,15,26,24 , 43 ,36) 
                    AND gtab10_9.trdate < Cast('2014-06-01'   AS timestamp)                 
                then gtab10_9.qty else 0 
            end) as OpeningOutQty,
            SUM( case 
                when gtab10_9.acyrid = 7 
                    and gtab10_9.vrid in(12 ,32 ,33 ,44 ,45 ,46 ,47,48,49) 
                    AND gtab10_9.trdate BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31'               
                then gtab10_9.qty else 0 
            end) as PrMthSaleQty,
            SUM( case 
                when gtab10_9.acyrid = 7 
                    and gtab10_9.vrid in( 12, 32 , 33 , 44 ,45 ,46 , 47,48 , 49) 
                    and (gtab10_9.FreeOrRpl = 0 OR gtab10_9.FreeOrRpl = 2) 
                    AND gtab10_9.trdate BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31'               
                then gtab10_9.qty * gtab10_9.ptr else 0 
            end) as PrMthSaleAmt,
            MAX( case 
                when gtab10_9.acyrid = 7 
                    and gtab10_9.VrId in (12,32,33,44,45,46, 47,48,49)
                    and (gtab10_9.FreeOrRpl = 0 OR gtab10_9.FreeOrRpl = 2) 
                then gtab10_9.TrDate else null 
            end) as LastSaleDate
        FROM (
            SELECT gtab10.*, gtab09.*
            FROM gtab10 
            INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab09.TranId = gtab10.TranId 
            inner join gtab4_5 on   gtab4_5.Productid = gtab10.Productid and gtab4_5.BatchId = gtab10.BatchId
        ) gtab10_9 
        group by gtab10_9.Productid, gtab10_9.BatchId
    ) stats_ags
    on stats_ags.Productid = gtab04.Productid 
    and stats_ags.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId
WHERE (gtab04.Masked = False AND gtab04.Banned = false)  
    AND  gtab04.patentid in  (321, 313 , 267 , 431) 
ORDER BY Patent, gtab04.Product
```

My results with this query:

```
Sort  (cost=82928.96..82931.84 rows=1152 width=306) (actual time=447.433..450.191 rows=2421 loops=1)
  Sort Key: gtab07.patent, gtab04.product
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 680kB
```

Vs original variant:

```
Sort  (cost=2796544.62..2796547.50 rows=1152 width=278) (actual time=47865.883..47868.570 rows=2421 loops=1)
  Sort Key: gtab07.patent, gtab04.product
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 680kB
```

Size for sort and rows count still same as suposed to be...

Measures based on your samples data PG 9.3

Comment: These cases in aggregations are cool. If the result is the same, way to go. :)

Comment: what if `gtab04.patentid in  (select patentid from gtab07)`

Comment: @keet sorry, don't get question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for optimizing this query, as i see it without running it.

- OpeningInQty can be calculated with OR condition, only 1 select will
  be needed
- LastSaleDate can be selected with MAX function, ordering is more
  expensive
- Ordering the whole query should be done after the quer is calculated,
  moved the whole thing into subquery
- Maybe You can use left join with subquery on gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09
  and grouping them by vrid. You can reuse it for results in outer
  query then. Filtering only by FreeOrRpl or doing this Case thing in
  the outer clause.

Here is my version of the SQL, i would appreciate if you share the QUERY PLAN with me.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    gtab04.Productid,
    gtab04.Product,
    gtab04.SaleUnit ,
    gtab04.Packing,
    gtab04.ConvFact,
    gtab04.PTR,
    gtab04.MRP, 
    gtab04.PRate,
    gtab04.PTR1,
    gtab04.PTR2,
    gtab04.Location,
    0 As ManufId,
    gtab07.PatentId,
    gtab07.Patent,
    gtab07.PatentCd,
    gtab15.TaxId,
    gtab15.TaxName, 
    gtab15.TaxType,
    gtab15.TaxRate, 
    gtab15.TxOMRP,
    ''::text As Manufacture,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(
      SELECT gtab10.Productid 
        FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab10.TranId = gtab09.TranId
        WHERE  gtab10.Productid = gtab04.Productid AND gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId 
            AND gtab09.acyrid = 7 limit 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   
  AS 
    StkEntered,
      (SELECT SUM(gtab10.qty) 
        FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab10.TranId = gtab09.TranId 
        WHERE gtab10.Productid = gtab04.Productid AND gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId 
            AND (gtab09.vrid = 6 
                OR (gtab09.vrid in (10, 11, 23, 42, 35) AND gtab09.trdate < Cast('2014-06-01' AS timestamp))
            AND gtab09.acyrid = 7)  
  AS 
  OpeningInQty
      (SELECT SUM(gtab10.qty)
        FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab10.TranId = gtab09.TranId  
        WHERE gtab10.Productid = gtab04.Productid AND gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId 
            AND gtab09.vrid in ( 12, 32, 33, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 18, 34, 25, 27, 15, 26, 24, 43, 36) 
                AND gtab09.trdate < Cast('2014-06-01' AS timestamp) AND gtab09.acyrid = 7) 
    AS 
    OpeningOutQty,
    0 AS PurchQty, 
    0 AS SRetQty, 
    0 AS PerInQty, 
    0 AS SaleQty, 
    0 AS StockInQty,
    0 AS StockOutQty, 
    0 AS SaleAmt, 
    0 AS DamageQty, 
    0 AS PRetQty, 
    0 AS PerOutQty,
      (SELECT SUM(gtab10.qty) 
        FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab10.TranId = gtab09.TranId 
        WHERE gtab10.Productid = gtab04.Productid AND gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId 
                AND gtab09.vrid in (12, 32, 33, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49) 
                AND (gtab09.trdate BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31')
      ) 
    AS 
    PrMthSaleQty, 
      (SELECT SUM(gtab10.qty * gtab10.ptr) 
        FROM gtab10 INNER JOIN gtab09 ON gtab10.TranId = gtab09.TranId 
        WHERE gtab10.Productid = gtab04.Productid  
            AND gtab10.BatchId = gtab05.BatchId 
            AND gtab09.vrid in (12, 32, 33, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49) 
            AND (gtab09.trdate BETWEEN  '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31') 
            AND (FreeOrRpl IN (0, 2))
      ) 
    AS 
    PrMthSaleAmt, 
    gtab04.LandCost,
    gtab05.PTR AS BatchPTR,
        (case when (
        gtab05.Fqty - gtab05.FIQty)>0 then (gtab05.Fqty -  gtab05.FIQty) else 0 end) as 
    IssdFreeQty, 
    gtab05.MRP AS BatchMRP, 
    gtab05.PRate AS BatchPRate, 
    gtab04.StdPack,  
    (date_part('day', (Select Min(Expiry) From gtab05 
    WHERE  gtab05.Productid = gtab04.Productid And gtab05.Qty > gtab05.IQty)-Cast('2014-06-20' AS    
        timestamp))) 
    AS 
    ExpDys, 
        (SELECT  MAX(gtab09.TrDate) FROM gtab09 INNER JOIN gtab10 ON gtab09.TranId  = gtab10.TranId   
        where gtab09.VrId in (12,32,33,44,45,46, 47,48,49) And gtab10.ProductId = gtab04.ProductId) 
  AS 
    LastSaleDate ,
    GTAB05.BatchId, 
    0 AS FreeSaleQty, 
    0 AS ReplSaleQty 
FROM gtab04 
    LEFT JOIN gtab05 ON gtab04.Productid = gtab05.Productid AND gtab04.patentid in (321, 313, 267, 431)
    INNER JOIN  gtab15 ON gtab04.TaxId = gtab15.TaxId      
    INNER JOIN gtab07 ON gtab04.Patentid = gtab07.Patentid   
WHERE (gtab04.Masked = False AND gtab04.Banned = false)  
) v
ORDER BY v.Patent, v.Product
```