# PostgreSQL:how to update rows in CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

am running `PostgreSQL 9.2`.

below given is a sample of my *huge and ugly*`query`

```
with cte as(
select ....... from aTable 
),cte1 as (
select ..... from bTable inner join cte using(anID)
),update_cte as(
update cte set aField=(select somthing from cte1)
)
select * from cte
```

i need to create a `view` with the final *result*.

while executing the above am getting an error which is below.

```
ERROR:  relation "cte" does not exist
```

I know am doing something bad.
hope you can understand what am trying to achieve from the above *query*.

So please suggest any alternative method for it.

Replies are much appreciated.

Note : [the actual query](http://pastebin.com/UX4sYi3f)

Comment: No, it's not at all clear what you're trying to do here.  It looks like you want to modify the contents of the first cte; but that's a transient, intermediate value computed for the purpose of another query.

Comment: @IfLoop is there any other way to achieve it ??

Comment: achieve what, I have no idea why you want this, or what it might do, or what it even means.  Can you give an example of what data this might return?

Comment: do i need to use `WITH RECURSIVE` instead ?

Comment: You may need to supply a full, un-edited query here.

Comment: @CraigRinger its really  a huge one that's why i put a sample here

Comment: @CraigRinger just see the actual [query](http://pastebin.com/UX4sYi3f)

Comment: @CraigRinger the select query in first `cte` is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301813/how-simplify-a-select-query-that-contains-many-inner-selects-and-increase-perfor)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
with cte as(
select ....... from aTable
),update_cte as(
update cte set aField=(select somthing from cte1)
)
```

You can't do that.

An `UPDATE` may not reference a CTE term in PostgreSQL, as CTEs are materialized. They aren't just views over the underlying data. (That's sometimes really annoying, but that's how it is).

You can:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW someview AS SELECT ... FROM atable;

UPDATE someview SET afield = ...
```

if you want; that'll work on newer PostgreSQL versions that support automatically updatable views. I think 9.2 does.

Otherwise, I think you want something like:

```
WITH cte1 as (
  select ..... from bTable inner join cte using(anID)
)
update aTable 
set aField=(select somthing from cte1)
WHERE ... where clause from cte ...
RETURNING *;
```

but really, please *don't* call your CTE terms `cte`, `cte1`, etc. Give them useful, descriptive names that tell you what they are. It's like programs full of variables named `a` through `x` ... the next person who has to maintain your code, or anyone you ask for help, will *not* like it.

Comment: _if you want; that'll work on newer PostgreSQL versions that support automatically updatable views. I think 9.2 does_ >  you meant `materialized views` ?

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW someview AS SELECT ... FROM atable;` in this the select collecting data between two _date_ so, does it really useful? actually the main _goal_ of the  _query_ is to find out the _stock and sales of all products_ user can select _date from_ and _date to_ on the basis of these date I need to query the tables

Comment: and one more thing _UPDATE someview SET afield = ..._ > is it possible to update a `VIEW` ??

Comment: @keet Er, yes. That's why I wrote that. See the documentation. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html . As for the first comment - no idea, when speaking in such general terms. All I can show you is "well, you can do this" and *you* determine if it fits your actual needs.

Comment: It's now possible to use `UPDATE` inside a CTE. See the section ["Data-Modifying Statements in WITH" in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).