# Updating String in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a given database table "Animals",a column called 'anim_name" existed as shown in the picture below
[image]

to update the anim_name so that there won't be a '-' .

Example:

```
'TE-MAEWA 04000' should update as 'TE MAEWA 04000' 
'TE-MAEWA 04354 CHAROLAIS CROSS' should update as 'TE MAEWA 04354 CHAROLAIS CROSS'
```

The following update statement is wrong

```
 update animals 
    set anim_name = 'TE MAEWA%'
  where soc_code = 'AUDV' 
    and anim_name like 'TE-MAEWA%'
```

because this would update every animal name to 'TE MAEWA%'. what would be the right update statement.

Comment: I would create a CTE that selects the uuid of the row, and the anim_name without the -. Then use that CTE to do an update with a join.  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25358642/4080476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function [`replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html):

```
update animals
set anim_name = replace(anim_name, 'TE-MAEWA', 'TE MAEWA')
where soc_code = 'AUDV' and anim_name like 'TE-MAEWA%';
```